# How to pass an id to modal using thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-ee, modal-dialog, thymeleaf

I'm working on a spring boot project,
I want to pass a simple id to my modal, the modal is just for ask to the user if He confirm the item deletion, if he confirm i want to send to my controller class /profil/{id}
but i don't understand how to pass my object id to the modal, it's my first spring boot project, I have no bases in JS...

my html code :

```
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
               Rendre disponible
             </button>

             <!-- Modal -->
             <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
               <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                 <div class="modal-content">
                   <div class="modal-header">
                     <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Rendre disponible</h5>
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                     </button>
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-body">
                     Voulez vous rendre ce topo à son propriétaire ?
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmer</button>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

you can use `th:data` to pass parameters to modal.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
    th:data-yourid="id_you_want_to_pass" data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#exampleModal">Rendre disponible</button>
```

And you can get this value using `javascript`. The following will be triggered as soon as modal is about to show.

```
$('#exampleModal).on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

    var id= $(e.relatedTarget).data('yourid);    
    //do whatever you want to do with this id

});
```